# Make bindings aware of ancestor bindings

Tags: python, c++, perl, swig

I have a C++ class derived from a library class.

```
class Derived : public LargeLibrary::ParentWithHugeInterface
{
  // add some methods
  // override some other methods
};
```

This library has its own Python and Perl bindings (created with SWIG). Now I want to create similar bindings for my own class. Can I make my bindings aware of `LargeLibrary`'s legacy to get to use `Derived` with `LargeLibrary`'s methods and get its parent's interface?

Update:
I have found Python's `PyTypeObject* PyTypeObject.tp_base` slot, however I still cannnot understand how to make use of it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I've found the solution.

It's as simple as adding `%import "LargeLibrary.i"` in the interface file.